# Webpack sass-loader doesn't understand '@' and throws error

Tags: angular, sass, webpack

I have issue with loading scss file across webpack. I saw, many people has same problem, and there was no explanation.

Basicly, I got error:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/theme.scss
Module parse failed: C:\Users\pi15463\www\crm_ng2\src\app\theme.scss Unexpected character '@' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected character '@' (1:0)
```

My theme Scss:

```
@import 'theme/variables/variables.scss';
@import 'theme/mixins/mixins.scss';
@import 'theme/nba.component.scss';
@import 'theme/layout.scss';
```

my webpack common config:

```
{
                 test: /\.scss$/,
                 loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ fallbackLoader: 'style-loader', loader: 'css-loader!sass-loader?sourceMap' }),
                 include: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
                 exclude: helpers.root('node_modules')
             }
```

webpack dev config:

```
plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin({ filename: '[name].css', allChunks: true })

    ],
```

I Tryied almost everything, and still, still same. How can it be, that sass-loader doesn't know what '@' is? Please help!

Comment: I believe style-loader needs to be part of the regular load sequence, not just as a fallback. Something like `loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader?sourceMap`

Comment: What is `helpers.root()`? Does it generate Windows paths properly? The problem is _not_ that the SASS loader doesn't recognize `@`, the problem is that the SASS loader isn't being called at all. A quick fix might be to just remove the `include` property from your loader config.

Comment: @robertklep Helpers.root is a helper func which is checking, that root dir are root. nothing more. I saw that sass-loader doesn't run at all, because I can't valid even simple css with it. Why sass loader-doesn't work at all, I got node-sass and sass-loader installed correctly...

Comment: @MarioTacke I tried with your loader sentence, and nothing, Basicly for dev configuration I prefer to use ExtractTextPlugin().

Comment: @UlandNimblehoof did you try removing `include` entirely? That's usually the reason why a loader isn't being used by Webpack.

Answer (score 1):

I solve that problem by those steps (Now, I have no problem with Unexpected character '@'):

In Root Component:

```
import './theme.scss';
@Component({

    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <a routerLink="/nba">nba</a>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>`
})
```

in Webpack.common:

```
 {
       test: /\.scss$/,
       loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader?sourceMap',
       exclude: helpers.root('node_modules')
 }
```